# Find which colnames are undefined and create them

Tags: r

So I have data frame

```
povprecja.predmeti
```

[image]

and in this data.frame have columns named:

`"krediti_razporejanje_n_2"

 "krediti_razporejanje_n_3"

 "krediti_razporejanje_n_4" 
 "krediti_razporejanje_n_5"`

I would like to generate/define another column name 
`krediti_razporejanje_n_1`, so **I would always have 5 column names defined**. But because of different data frames I would like to have dinamic code, this means

I would like to find which (from krediti_razporejanje_n_1 to krediti_razporejanje_n_5) colname is undefined and define this column name and fill it with values 0. So if my example I am mising column

```
krediti_razporejanje_n_1 which I would like to assign <- 0
```

I know I could do it by hand like:

```
povprecja.predmeti$krediti_razporejanje_n_1 <- rep(0,nrow(povprecja.predmeti))
```

but i need a function, so if my data there are just two colnames defined, find which from 1-5 are undefined and define them.

I can find which one is missing with this code

```
which(paste0("krediti_razporejanje_n_", 1:5) %in% colnames(povprecja.predmeti)==FALSE)
```

But I would like to have dinamic function.

Comment: What do you mean "dinamic function"? Give in your question what such a function definition might look like. Something like: `D = add_columns(data=D, prefix="foo_", n=1:12)`? Given a data frame `D` create any missing columns `foo_1` to `foo_12`? Is that a minimal summary of what you want to do here?

Comment: @Spacedman. I would always (for all my data in different csv) create columns from 1 -5 and named it (colnames) krediti_razporejanje_n_1 -krediti_razporejanje_n_5 . But Some  of my data (in other csv) have different combinations of columns (one data frame has just 2 columns defined krediti_razporejanje_n_1  and krediti_razporejanje_n_2) . So In all data I would like to find which column is missing or is undefined and define it accordingly to missing column.

Comment: okay, but general solutions are always better than specific ones. If your specific problem is a subset of the problems my proposed `add_columns` function can solve then that's what we need to write. You would then do `D=add_columns(D,"krediti_razporejanje_n_",1:5)`. Then next week when you have 6 columns or a different column name, its easy to use that same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
miscol <- function(x){
# x = data.frame
missing <- paste0("krediti_razporejanje_n_",1:5)[paste0("krediti_razporejanje_n_", 1:5) %in% colnames(x) == FALSE]
res <- list()
for(i in missing){
res[[i]] <- rep(0,nrow(x))
}
new <- data.frame(x,res)
return(new[,sort(colnames(new))])
}
```

As I am a new user and cannot comment, I guess I will have to answer. But this should do what you want it to do.

There probably is a better way to do it instead of using an empty list to write the new columns though. But this will take all the column names that are missing, give them all zeros and write it back into a new data-frame.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that does it:

```
add_missing <- function(D, prefix, n){
    current_names = names(D)
    final_names = paste0(prefix, 1:n)
    new_names = setdiff(final_names, current_names)
    for(n in new_names){
        D[[n]]=0
    }
    D = D[,order(names(D))]
    D
}
```

Test:

```
> d=data.frame(x_2=1:5, x_3=1:5, x_4=1:5, x_5=1:5)
> d
  x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5   5
> d = add_missing(d, "x_", 5)
> d
  x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5
1   0   1   1   1   1
2   0   2   2   2   2
3   0   3   3   3   3
4   0   4   4   4   4
5   0   5   5   5   5
```

Just check it doesn't fail if there's no missing columns:

```
> add_missing(d, "x_", 5)
  x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5
1   0   1   1   1   1
2   0   2   2   2   2
3   0   3   3   3   3
4   0   4   4   4   4
5   0   5   5   5   5
```

And now chop a few columns out and see what happens:

```
> d=d[,c(1,2,5)]
> d
  x_1 x_2 x_5
1   0   1   1
2   0   2   2
3   0   3   3
4   0   4   4
5   0   5   5
> add_missing(d, "x_", 5)
  x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5
1   0   1   0   0   1
2   0   2   0   0   2
3   0   3   0   0   3
4   0   4   0   0   4
5   0   5   0   0   5
```

And another test:

```
> add_missing(d, "x_", 7)
  x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 x_6 x_7
1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
2   0   2   0   0   2   0   0
3   0   3   0   0   3   0   0
4   0   4   0   0   4   0   0
5   0   5   0   0   5   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TJGorrie. I used your code and modify it a little bit, so the working solution in my example is:

```
if (any(paste0("krediti_razporejanje_n_", 1:5) %in% colnames(povprecja.predmeti)==FALSE)) { # x = data.frame missing <- paste0("krediti_razporejanje_n_",1:5)[paste0("krediti_razporejanje_n_", 1:5) %in% colnames(povprecja.predmeti) == FALSE] res <- list() for(i in missing){ povprecja.predmeti[[i]] <- rep(0,nrow(povprecja.predmeti)) } }
```